# SSH between EC2 instances not permitted

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, security-groups

I am setting up a few EC2 instances in a shared AWS account and want to give them access to each other. At the same time I want to prohibit access from other instances in the account.

I created a security group and added SSH access from "My IP" for logging in and that works well.

Now I need to SSH *between* all of the instances but I can't even though they are all in the *same security group*.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you're setting up some cluster on AWS and need SSH access between the nodes, correct? You have 2 options:

1. The naive one is to add each instance IP to the Security Group Inbound list - but that means you'll need to update the SG every time you add a new instance in the cluster. (If you ever do). *Don't do this,* I only mentioned it for completeness.
2. *Far better* is to **use the Security Group ID** itself as the **source of the traffic**.

   It's important to understand that SG is not only an *inbound filter* but also tags all *outbound* traffic - and you can then refer to the originating SG ID in the same or other security groups.

Have a look at the *default* security group in your VPC. You'll most likely see something like this:

[image: self-referencing security group]

Note that the rule refers to the **Security Group ID** *itself*.

With this rule everything that originates from any host that's a member of your security group will be accepted by all other members / instances in the group.

In your case you may want to restrict it to SSH, ICMP (if you need `ping` working) or any other ports you need.

Also check the *Outbound* tab and make sure that it has an entry for *All traffic* to `0.0.0.0/0` (unless you've got specific security needs), otherwise the instances won't be able to initiate any outbound connections. By default it should be there.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 4):

In the configuration for your security group you want to use to allow SSH between the instances:

1. Go to the **Inbound** tab

   1. Click **Edit**
   2. Click **Add Rule**
   3. For **Type** select **SSH**
   4. For **Source** enter the Security Group ID
   5. **Save**
2. Go to the **Oubound** tab

   1. Click **Edit**
   2. Click **Add Rule**
   3. For **Type** select **SSH**
   4. For **Destination** enter the Security Group ID
   5. **Save**

Answer (score 2):

You should add a rule that enables SSH with source being the group ID itself.

E.g. if your security group id is `sg-12345678` you can add a rule in that very group that opens *SSH* from `sg-12345678`.

Also make sure that the *Outbound* tab has a rule for `0.0.0.0/0` or at least again for SSH to `sg-12345678` otherwise the outbound traffic will be blocked. By default the `0.0.0.0/0` should be there.

Answer (score 0):

allow ssh access for the security group you assigned to them.